# Regular expression find 3 or 4 numbers

Tags: sed, regular-expression

So, I have 50+ words and I have to match the numbers in them. These numbers can be 3 or 4 digit numbers. I think I tried every way there is, but nothing seems to work (I need to remember the number as a pattern).
My attempts:

```
'/\(.*\)\([0-9][0-9]?[0-9][0-9]\)\(.*\)/'
'/\(.*\)\([0-9]\{3,4\}\)\(.*\)/'
'/\(.*\)\(([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\)\(.*\)/'
...
```

It always matches only 3 numbers, or the whole word.

**INPUT:**

```
1844-PAL.Bak 
IMG_1959.bak  
ZER_1940.BAK  
PEN225.bak
word-1943.BAK
```

**NEED TO REMEMBER AS A PATTERN:**

```
1844
1959
1940
225
1943
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of your input?

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, but is that an example of one of your input lines? Please show us a few lines of your file and your desired output. Can all 4 examples be on the same line or does each line only have one of these forms?

Comment: oh, okay, sorry. didn't think it would matter. give me a minute. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The following commands assume that each input line can only have one number. I am using this file as a test:

```
1844-PAL.Bak 
IMG_1959.bak  
ZER_1940.BAK  
PEN225.bak
word-1943.BAK
```

1. `sed`

   ```
   $ sed -r 's/([^0-9]*)([0-9]*)([^0-9]*)/1:"\1", 2:"\2", 3:"\3"/' file
   1:"", 2:"1844", 3:"-PAL.Bak "
   1:"IMG_", 2:"1959", 3:"bak  "
   1:"ZER_", 2:"1940", 3:"BAK  "
   1:"PEN", 2:"225", 3:"bak"
   1:"word-", 2:"1943", 3:"BAK"
   ```
2. `perl`

   ```
   $ perl -lpe 's/([^\d]*)(\d*)([^\d])/1:"$1", 2:"$2", 3:"$3"/' file
   1:"", 2:"1844", 3:"-"PAL.Bak 
   1:"IMG_", 2:"1959", 3:"."bak  
   1:"ZER_", 2:"1940", 3:"."BAK  
   1:"PEN", 2:"225", 3:"."bak
   1:"word-", 2:"1943", 3:"."BAK
   ```
3. `grep`

   ```
   $ grep -oP '\d+' file
   1844
   1959
   1940
   225
   1943
   ```

---

If you only have one pattern of interest per line, you can simplify to

```
 $ sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9]*).*/Matched: \1/' file
Matched: 1844
Matched: 1959
Matched: 1940
Matched: 225
Matched: 1943
```

or

```
$ perl -lpe 's/.*?(\d+).*/Matched $1/' file
Matched 1844
Matched 1959
Matched 1940
Matched 225
Matched 1943
```

In general, with regular expressions, less is more. You should always try and use the simplest regular expression necessary. If you don't want to capture or match the non-number characters, then leave them out of the regex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only thing though - in the sed version (the first one there) it does leave a dot there in "\2". Any chance we can get rid of that?

Comment: @Wanderer yes, sorry, I did that before you added your input since I assumed that you would also want to match decimal numbers. See updated answer. Also, I suggest you use the simpler `sed` one at the end, no need for the complexity of the first versions for what you are attempting.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below GNU `grep` command,

```
grep -oP '[0-9]{3,4}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e "s/^[^0-9]*//g" -e "s/\(^[0-9]*\)\(.*\)/\1/" <file_name>
```

one another way to do this

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' <file_name>
```

Comment: Please elaborate, why this is an answer to the question (which I believe it is not).